# Cef browser form is coming up blank after Form.Hide(); / Form.Show();

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I am using cefsharp on a winforms project to display a browser form on top of my main form, both of them inside and MDIParent. When i am calling the browser form it draws correctly navigating to the requested site. In the form i have a button to hide it, so the main form comes back up. When I request again for the browser form to .Show() it comes up blank.

```
public partial class MDIParent1 : Form
{
   //this is the browser form
    static Eztvit ezForm = new Eztvit();

    public MDIParent1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        setStatusText("Initializing...");
        //this is the main form
        comparisonForm cForm = new comparisonForm();
        cForm.MdiParent = this;
        cForm.Show();            
        cForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        setStatusText("Ready");
        ezForm.MdiParent = this;
        ezForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ezForm.Show();

    }
```

}

And in the browser form i got this button:

```
    private void backBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                       
        this.Hide();
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your contributions.

Comment: Does it act differently if you remove the word `static`?

Comment: No. Same behavior. It was a non static instance when i first wrote it.

Comment: What version are you using? Is the form handle being re-created? You'll probably have to debug the source yourself to see what's actually going on.

Comment: @amaitland I'm having a similar issue to the one in this question: in my case the form handle does change - what does that signify?

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem when reshowing from the same UI thread by using Invoke/BeginInvoke. The cef browser thread seems to deadlock and no other calls will be honored (like ShowDevTools or change url).
Your case is similar in that the Hide() call is being executed on the UI thread (coming from the button handler) so I would suggest to try putting that Hide() call in a separate Task or Thread.

Comment: `Hide` can only be called on the `WinForms UI Thread`. You'll get an exception if you attempt to execute on any other thread. I have doubts that the behaviour you are seeing is an actual deadlock, though without an example it's impossible to say. If you are having problems I'd suggest creating your own question.